# EasyMock: Mocked object is calling actual method

Tags: unit-testing, mocking, easymock

I've following code snippet in my unit test,

```
ClassToBeMocked mock = createMock(ClassToBeMocked.class); //I've statically imported EasyMock.*
mock.callMethod(); //This is a void method
expectLastCall();
replay(mock);
```

But when I run the test, instead of seeting up the expectaion, callMethod() is actually called. Am I doing something wrong?

I'm fairly new to EasyMock or any mocking framework and blocked because of this problem. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
AndyS

Comment: Is ClassToBeMocked a concrete class or an interface? Also, which version of EasyMock are you using?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This will happen if you are mocking a class with a 'final' method. EasyMock does not override a final method. If you cannot mock an interface, and you cannot change the method to non-final, you can use [PowerMock](http://code.google.com/p/powermock/) along with EasyMock to get around this limitation.  That specific use case is described [here](http://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/MockFinal).