# Easymock andReturn(a mock) returns null

Tags: java, unit-testing, easymock

Using EasyMock 3.2, I have a test that is essentially the same as the one I have below. When I run this test there is a null pointer exception when the SUT tries to do `daoSupport.getHibernateTemplate().loadAll();` When the mocked daoSupport is supposed to return the mocked template, it returns `null`.

```
@RunWith(EasyMockRunner.class)
public class DAOImplTest extends EasyMockSupport {
    @Mock
    private HibernateDaoSupport daoSupport;
    @Mock
    private HibernateTemplate template;

    @Test
    public void test() {
        expect(daoSupport.getHibernateTemplate()).andReturn(template).once(); //1
        expect(template.loadAll()).andReturn(Collections.emptyList()).once(); //2
        replayAll();

        SUT mySUT = new SUT(daoSupport);
        mySUT.exercise();
        verifyAll();
    }
}
```

I can get the test to work by replacing `//1` in the snippet above here with

```
daoSupport.setHibernateTemplate(template);
```

Obviously this is not what I want to do. I want the mocked daoSupport to return the mocked template. What is wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason, as discribed in the [EasyMock documentation](http://easymock.org/EasyMock3_2_Documentation.html):

> Final methods cannot be mocked. If called, their normal code will be executed.

It just so happens that `HibernateDaoSupport#getHibernateTemplate()` is `final`. Since I can not change the method signature, the best I can do is to extract an interface for this class. Alternatively I can use Powermock, as mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7211260/297331).

At the end of the day, executing the normal code of the getter is not so bad. It's just a getter.

Comment: Strange that EasyMock "silently fails" in this case... Mockito throws an exception.